# Php convert multidimensional array to single array

Tags: php, arrays

How can I convert multidimensional array into single array

**Input**

```
[["4|1","4|3","4|6"],[["4|1|2","4|1|8"],["4|3|4","4|3|9"],["4|6|5","4|6|12"]]]
```

**How can I convert above input as below ?**

```
["4|1","4|3","4|6","4|1|2","4|1|8","4|3|4","4|3|9","4|6|5","4|6|12"]
```

Comment: Show us what you tried, please. (The way of doing it without any fancy array functions using simple loops is rather trivial, so you should at least have something to show.)

Answer (score 2):

I see you want to flatten an array to 1-D. Here is recursive iterator class you can use,

```
$arr = [["4|1","4|3","4|6"],[["4|1|2","4|1|8"],["4|3|4","4|3|9"],["4|6|5","4|6|12"]]];
$iterator = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(new \RecursiveArrayIterator($arr));
$result = [];
foreach($iterator as $v) {
  $result[] = $v;
}
print_r($result);
```

[RecursiveArrayIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php) - This iterator allows to unset and modify values and keys while iterating over Arrays and Objects in the same way as the [ArrayIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayiterator.php). Additionally, it is possible to iterate over the current iterator entry.

[Ref](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php#102574).

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/UjKJE)

**Solution 2:-**

```
$arr = [["4|1","4|3","4|6"],[["4|1|2","4|1|8"],["4|3|4","4|3|9"],["4|6|5","4|6|12"]]];
array_walk_recursive($arr, function($v) use(&$result){
  $result[] = $v;
});
print_r($result);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/iYdDM)

**Output:-**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4|1
    [1] => 4|3
    [2] => 4|6
    [3] => 4|1|2
    [4] => 4|1|8
    [5] => 4|3|4
    [6] => 4|3|9
    [7] => 4|6|5
    [8] => 4|6|12
)
```

Comment: getting this error when i try your solution Class 'App\Http\Controllers\RecursiveArrayIterator' not found

Comment: which PHP version you are using? Check my solution 2 of an updated answer. Try to add \ to the class which is giving that error.

Comment: solution 2 working.thanks :)

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_merge()`.

```
$arrays = [["4|1","4|3","4|6"],[["4|1|2","4|1|8"],["4|3|4","4|3|9"],["4|6|5","4|6|12"]]]
$arrayMerge = []
foreach($arrays as $array)
{
    $arrayMerge = array_merge($arrayMerge, $array)
}
```

For more info: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-merge.php

Comment: This results in: `array (
  0 => '4|1',
  1 => '4|3',
  2 => '4|6',
  3 => 
  array (
    0 => '4|1|2',
    1 => '4|1|8',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    0 => '4|3|4',
    1 => '4|3|9',
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    0 => '4|6|5',
    1 => '4|6|12',
  ),
)` which is not what the OP desires.

Comment: Given the input above, you could do: `array_merge(...array_merge([array_shift($in)], ...$in));` but a recursive approach would be less brittle.

Comment: Yes, i didnt see you had differents deep level in your input. Sorry. In this case is better you use Rahul answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution. I have used a couple of foreach loops to make it simple.

```
<?php 
$array = [["4|1","4|3","4|6"],[["4|1|2","4|1|8"],["4|3|4","4|3|9"],["4|6|5","4|6|12"]]];

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if($key == 0)
    {
        foreach ($value as $key => $v) {
            $new_array[] = $v;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach ($value as $key => $s_value) {
            foreach ($s_value as $key => $s) {
                $new_array[] = $s;
            }
        }
    }
}


print_r($new_array);

 ?>
```

Here is the [live demo](https://3v4l.org/nc8j9) for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_walk_recursive`, check [Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4c21d65a6ba125e05217a6744a3c65aa815f21d4)

```
$result = [];
$multidimension_array = [["4|1","4|3","4|6"],[["4|1|2","4|1|8"],["4|3|4","4|3|9"],["4|6|5","4|6|12"]]];
array_walk_recursive($multidimension_array, function($v) use (&$result) { $result[] = $v; });
print_r($result);
```